# Is is possible that Tuxera NTFS driver is faulty in listing some filenames?

Tags: mac, ntfs, ntfs-3g

I'm dual booting Windows and Mac ML, and I'm try to access a file on both operating systems. This file is a song file with japanese characters in it. Windows has no issues accessing this file, however Mac refuses to list the files in Finder. The file is listed when using the `ls` command on both Windows and Mac. On Mac this file cannot be opened to be read. Mac currently uses Tuxera for NTFS drives, but I have it disabled for the drive that this file is located on.

Here are the things I've tested:

In python, I went into the directory containing the music file using `os.chdir`, then proceeded with `os.listdir(u'.')`. All the files are listed including the music file. I copy the filename of the problematic file into a variable `m`. I attempt to open it with `open(m, 'rb')` but receive a file-not-found exception. So I take `m` and create an empty file elsewhere, like on my desktop on Mac which has the HFS+ case-sensitive filesystem. It can read and write, and I was able to delete it from the desktop successfully. I repeated the procedure to create the file on my desktop elsewhere, like on my external hard drive that is formatted as NTFS and yielded the same results.

The drive of the folder of the problematic file has the Tuxera driver disabled, and the external hard drive I used to test the creation of a file with the same name has it enabled. I decided to test again after disabling Tuxera on the external and found no problems creating/reading/writing the test file with the same name.

The filename of the file in question is as below:
`u'03 \u5929\u79e4 \uff5e\u5f37\u304b\u3099\u308a\u306a\u79c1 x \u5f31\u304b\u3099\u308a\u306a\u541b\uff5e.flac'`

I just want to know if this is a bug with Tuxera or not.

Comment: Sure I suppose its possible.  Contact the authors of Tuxera and report the issue.

Comment: Tested with Tuxera ntfs-3g on Linux; does not have this problem. Might be OSX-specific.

Comment: Thanks, like I said I tested it on other Tuxera enabled drives and do not have the problem. Are there any ways to enable verbose NTFS driver logging to further diagnose the issue?